# Filtering a tibble into two tibbles based on if a column's value is increasing or decreasing

Tags: r, filter, tibble

I am trying to filter a tibble into two tibbles. My data involves a column which is the variable (V) which is being controlled - so the data continously increases up to a value, and then decreases from that value.  I would like to end up with one tibble with the part of the data for which V is increasing, and one tibble where V is decreasing. The point where the change happens can be filtered into the first data set.
[Filter items based on whether the amount is increasing or decreasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320734/filter-items-based-on-whether-the-amount-is-increasing-or-decreasing)

But this doesn't really work for my problem - I want to filter the V values based on if they are higher or lower than the V value in the row before.

I tried:

```
rawfilt <- raw %>% 
    mutate(status=case_when(
    first(V) < last(V) ~ "Increasing",
    last(V) < first(V) ~ "Decreasing"))
```

But this just gives that everything is decreasing. (as the last value is lower than the first.

As an example data looks like:

| t | V |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 |

And I would liek to end up with:

Tibble 1:

| t | V |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

Tibble 2:

| t | V |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 |

Comment: So what's the desired output here? Where does the 4 value go? And the end of the increasing or at the start of the decreasing? Or is it repeated?

Comment: @MrFlick I want to output two tables - one with the part of the data which has the increasing V values, and one where it is decreasing

Comment: Again, where does the value for 4 in the V column go? Does it go in the increasing or decreasing tibble? What if the values fluctuate up and down even more? What if they stay the same? We need more specific rules for transforming the data.

Comment: Ah apologies - it can go to the first one. The values don't stay the same or fluctuate as I am changing the V variable in the experiment so it gradually increases and gradually decreases.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is doing the following using `ifelse`:

```
> data.frame(
+   't' = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
+   'v' = c(2, 3, 4, 3)
+ ) |> 
+   mutate(status = ifelse(t < v, "Increasing", "Decreasing")) 

  t v     status
1 1 2 Increasing
2 2 3 Increasing
3 3 4 Increasing
4 4 3 Decreasing
```

Other option using `case_when`:

```
> data.frame(
+   't' = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
+   'v' = c(2, 3, 4, 3)
+ ) |> 
+   mutate(status = case_when(t < v ~ "Increasing", 
+                             TRUE ~ "Decreasing")) 

  t v     status
1 1 2 Increasing
2 2 3 Increasing
3 3 4 Increasing
4 4 3 Decreasing
```

Comment: Thanks! I think because this considers the case when V is < or > than t, it doesn't fully work. I want to only compare relative V values if that makes sense

Comment: @Kieran I think you would get more help and an exact solution if you followed some of the comments made by MrFlick. Please provided your expected output in your question so users do not have to guess what you want. Based on your description, this seems like a fine solution. "I want to only compare relative V values" does not clarify much. Could you attempt to show what you mean?